# Can an MVC 5 application (deployed on Azure) have authentication like windows authentication ( no login page)?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-active-directory

We are planning to implement our enterprise application as an MVC 5 application, which will be deployed on Azure. We do not want any sort of login page. We did some research about Azure Active directory, but we are not sure whether following expectation will be meet if we enable Azure Active Directory and sync that with on premise AAD. Will someone please answer whether this would be possible:

User logs in to computer with his/her user ID  and password. H/she open the browser and attempts to go to MVC 5  app on Azure. Does s/he has to enter user id/password again or will s/he be able to land on the landing page?

Please suggest. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is absolutely possible, provided that the user is already signed in with the account associated to the azure AD directory the app is configured to use (for example, a user signed in a Windows 10 device with their Azure AD account).
There are two main considerations you need to apply:

- The URL on which the user lands must require the caller to be authenticated - for example, the controller class or the action must be protected with [Authorize]
- You must ensure that Azure AD doesn't prompt the user to choose what directory he/she is from, but automatically select their home directory. One way to do that is to pass the domain_hint, as discussed in http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/11/17/skipping-the-home-realm-discovery-page-in-azure-ad/.

Note that this works only if you know what is the home directory of the user; if you don't (e.g. you work with many different directories) you might devise some trick to keep track after the first authentication (e,g, your own tracking cookie) but the first auth will need to occur interactively (for discovering the directory).